# Call Sql Server stored procedure from arcpy

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, sql-server

Is there a way to execute a SQL Server stored procedure with arcpy or Python and retrieve the results returned by the stored procedure?

There is a very similar question posted [on ArcGIS forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/61724-How-to-execute-an-MS-SQL-stored-procedure-and-then-use-the-results-in-arcpy) with no answer so far.

Comment: Executing stored procedures via ArcSDESQLExecute is not supported:

import arcpy
sde_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(r"D:\ConnFiles\RDSQLDEV@KnownPoint@osa.sde")
sde_return = sde_conn.execute('EXEC usp_GIS_NewlyReleasedWellData')
produces:

return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.Execute(*gp_fixargs(args)))
AttributeError

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For working specifically with SQL Server, arguably the best Python package is [`pymssql`](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/) which is:

> A simple database interface for Python that builds on top of FreeTDS
>   to provide a Python DB-API (PEP-249) interface to Microsoft SQL
>   Server.

I have used it in production for many years making a ton of SQL SP calls and it worked really, really well.

Another package, [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/StoredProcedures), is also capable of executing stored procedures.
Check out the getting started guide [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted).

> It is a Python 2.x and 3.x module that allows you to use ODBC to
>   connect to almost any database from Windows, Linux, OS/X, and more.
>   It implements the Python Database API Specification v2.0, but
>   additional features have been added to simplify database programming
>   even more.
>
> Pyodbc is licensed using an MIT license, so it is free for commercial
>   and personal use. You can even use the source code in your own
>   projects. Installers for Windows are available here and most Linux distributions
>   are starting to provide pre-compiled packages. Full source code is
>   also available.

If you will ever need to execute SQL commands for an ArcSDE geodatabase, consider using the [ArcSDESQLExecute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000007z000000) class which provides a means of executing SQL statements via an ArcSDE connection. I am not sure though if you can shoot SQL commands for stored procedures, but it might be worth trying.

Comment: Thanks, I just tested pymssql library that works well with stored procedures. What about arcpy? I didn't find anywhere in the docs that it does not support stored procedures.

Comment: You can mix regular python with arcpy stuff. Arcpy is just a library for regular python. So do your normal Arcpy stuff, and then follow the pyodbc documentation to run those functions.

Comment: That is correct, you can use both ArcPy and Python code in the same file/module. If you will ever need to run SQL code with ArcPy and you don't have access to pyodbc library, I usually use ArcSDESQLExecute class which works however only with geodatabases (as far as I tested). I have updated my answer too.